# Cloud SQL Postgres Extensions: cloudsql_stat and google_insights

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Poking around in `pg_catalog.pg_available_extensions`, two extensions caught my eye for which I cannot find any documentation:

- cloudsql_stat:   Google Cloud SQL statistics extension
- google_insights: Google extension for database insights

Does anybody know anything about these two extensions?

Maybe cloudsql_stat will expose metrics that are otherwise not readily available as a managed service?

Maybe google_insight extensions suggests that Google is working on a service similar to AWS RDS' Performance Insight?

Comment: I filed a Feature Request on the GCP public issue tracker about this. The response for the moment is that the documentation is being updated and slated for publication in Q1 2021. Crossing fingers that I am right about the purpose of these extensions!

Comment: Could you share the link on the issue so anyone who gets to here can track the issue as well? and suscribe on the issue

Comment: Sure! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175864325

Comment: I attempted to CREATE EXTENSION with either of these and an error is reported that the extension is not currently supported by CloudSQL

I also reviewed available metrics for the cloudsql_instance_database resource type in Monitoring. The term 'insights" appears in some of the names and metrics like this do not currently appear to report any data. For example: cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/postgresql/insights/aggregate/execution_time

Wonder if there is a correlation between the two? We will see hopefully soon enough!

Comment: This came out. Cloud SQL Query Insight https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/get-ahead-of-database-performance-issues-with-cloud-sql-insights